# How Do I Get Rid of White Space in a Project Location

Tags: android

I just started using Android Studio and I'm trying to change the project location of my projects to my external hard drive for easier use when I'm on my laptop somewhere else.  But I get this message:

**Your project location contains whitespace. This can cause problem on some plateform and is not recommended**

I read in another post that one person just suggested to not have white space and I was wondering how I could get rid of that.  And if I can't what kind of problems would I face.  The other post from 2 months ago said importing and exporting would be an issue but wasn't very specific.  If it means all exporting then I guess I'll just deal with having it on my main drive instead of the external.

*extra* : *I would love any extra information about this kind of white space because every time I try to google it I get different kinds of white space questions that don't relate to file locations*

Comment: withspace in your project path (location). `c:\project123\stuff` vs. `c:\project 123\stuff`

Comment: you may replace them with `-`,  `_` or don't put them at all

Comment: Wow now i feel really stupid.  Thank you for your help =)

Answer (score 0):

I overcame this issue - I changed mine to c:\ProjectName\FolderName\AppName